# Recurrence relation problem with Grey's code

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have a problem solving a recurrent relation. Here it is:

We have n electric switches mounted to a wall and a lamp. There are two possible positions for these switches – on and off. You can’t know if a switch is turned on or off. The lamp turns on when all the switches are turned on. You have to find the minimum number of steps you need to do before the lamp turns on.

Here is how I solve it:

Let’s imagine the number of these switches as a string whose elements can take 2 options -> 0 (for being turned off) and 1 (for being turned on). The number of these elements is n, so the total number of possible permutations is 2^n. But since we start at 1 position we have to take out 1 of this number. So the minimum number of steps we have to do is 2^n – 1.

But we have a hint from our assistant. He told us we can use Grey’s code in solving this task. Can someone explain to me how do I solve it using Grey’s code? And can someone please tell me if my solution is right? Thanks a lot guys! :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Your current "proof" doesn't show that you have to switch only one switch between each combination you test. You have shown how many combinations to test, but not how many switches you have to switch to cycle through them all.

If you examine the Grey code you might see how this can be done efficiently.